# How to log into a webapp that uses Google sign-in, programmatically?

Tags: google-api, google-signin, google-oauth

There is a web application that I use regularly, and it uses Google OAuth for login. What I mean by that is that I get the following screen when I visit the application after a considerable amount of time.

[image: Webapp that uses Google OAuth]

Now, I want to develop an application, that directly makes a call to an API that this application makes a call to. But it turns out, the credentials that I send in the POST request work as long as I am logged into this application, but not after that. **So, is there a way that I can log into this application programmatically, say every 2 hours?**

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are looking for "offline access". When you send the request, you are sending an access token that expires after an hour.

With offline access, the first time you log in, you will get a refresh token (you need to store it in your database) that allows you to generate new access tokens (without you being present) when old tokens have expired.

I suggest you to take a look on [this link](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer#offline).

Hope this helps.